# How do I handle and display multiple form validation errors?

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have a form and need to validate it. So what I'm doing is

```
if(empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password)){
    $_SESSION['comp_form'] = "Complete all fields";
    header('Location: register.php');
}
if(strlen($password) < 5){
    $_SESSION['pass_leng'] = "Choose a longer password";
    header('Location: register.php');
}
```

I'm doing this because I need to display the Session on another page, but only one error gets shown. What I'm trying to do is something like this where all errors are shown at once.

[image]

Am I on the right track? Or is there another way to go about this. Because I can only display one message at a time using

```
$_SESSION['comp_form'] = "Complete all fields";
header('Location: register.php');
exit()
```

Comment: FYI, the example that you're showing is most likely using client-side validation.

Comment: Build up an array of errors during your validation, then check to see if there are errors in the array and redirect if there is. You could also use array keys to identify which field to show each error on.

Comment: Yeah I know. I just want to do this server side @PatrickQ

Comment: Can you show an example? I'm fairly new and any help would be great @scrowler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build up an array of errors during your validation, then check to see if there are errors in the array and redirect if there is. You could also use array keys to identify which field to show each error on.

Here's an example:

```
$errors = array();

if(empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password)){
    $errors['comp_form'] = "Complete all fields";
}
if(strlen($password) < 5){
    $errors['pass_leng'] = "Choose a longer password";
}

// more validation here if you wish
if(count($errors) > 0) {
    $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
    header("Location: register.php");
    exit;
} else {
    // clean up previous validation errors, everything's fine
    unset($_SESSION['errors']);
}
```

Then on your form you can check for errors:

```
<!-- add hasError class to input when validation failed to allow you to style it -->
<input type="password" name="password" class="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['pass_leng'])) echo 'hasError'; ?>">
<!-- if there's an error, output it on a generic error message element -->
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['pass_leng'])) echo '<p class="formError">' . $_SESSION['errors']['pass_leng'] . '</p>'; ?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'd suggest a certain amount of client side validation would benefit you in terms of your UX, e.g. clearing the error messages when a form becomes valid. It is totally essential to validate server side as well though.

Comment: I just added one more thing to clear the errors when the page gets refreshed. I used `unset($_SESSION['errors']);` on the actual form. So it might be worth putting it in the answer

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
$_SESSION['error'] = 0;
if(empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password)){
    $_SESSION['comp_form'] = "Complete all fields";
    $_SESSION['error'] = 1;
}
if(strlen($password) < 5){
    $_SESSION['pass_leng'] = "Choose a longer password";
    $_SESSION['error'] = 1;
}
if($_SESSION['error'] == 1){
    header('Location: register.php');
}
```

Just unless you want to use AJAX which will improve the smoothness of your Site at the cost of using JavaScript.

Comment: This is correct. When you do `header('Location: register.php');`, it is as if you wrote `exit()` or `return`. Anything that comes later in the code won't take effect, because the user has already "left" the page then. Just collect all errors first and _then_ do the redirect, like suggested here.

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of fields you require to be validated (which match up with their `$_POST` names):

```
$fields = array(
  'name'     => 'Name', 
  'username' => 'Username',
  'email'    => 'E-Mail',
  'password' => 'Password'
);
```

Then loop over them, if they aren't valid, add them to your `$_SESSION['errors']` array:

```
$_SESSION['errors'] = array(); 

foreach ($fields as $field => $niceName) {
    if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $_SESSION['errors'][$field] = $niceName . ' cannot be empty';
    } elseif ($field == 'password' && strlen($_POST[$field]) < 5) {
       $_SESSION['errors'][$field] = 'Choose a longer password';
    }      
}
```

Then, if `$_SESSION['errors']` isn't empty, you can redirect:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['errors'])) {
    header('Location: register.php');
    exit(); 
}
```

Comment: You should implement a key -> value pair to give a user label for each field, it would look a little naff to present "name cannot be empty", especially if more complicated field names were used... `confirm_password`, `foo_client_age_bar` etc.

Comment: Agreed, I often do something similar to the above when doing input validation. I think I misunderstood the question anyway :p